# Could you ever legitimately have an occurrence of "}{" in a JSON string

Tags: php, json, character, delimiter

I am generating a sequential string of independent JSON strings for insertion into a single field in my database (the means justify the end), and am wondering if a JSON string could ever legally have an occurrence of two opposing(ly) faced curly braces such as `}{`? As I would like to use this pattern as a delimiter if so.

I am using PHP's json_encode function for this purpose.

Should say that I don't mean as a value - or key if that were possible as I am in control of the data. Seems like a stupid question now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It can form part of a string in JSON text.

```
{
    "EskimoKiss": "}{"
}
```

If you *must* store multiple pieces of data expressed as JSON in a database field, then parse them to objects, wrap them in an array, then serialise that array to JSON and store that.

You really should normalise the data though.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that as long as I know it's not going to be a value

Comment: So json_encoding the array directly is not the best approach then? How might I "parse them to objects, wrap them in an array, then serialise that array to JSON"?. cheers